# How to get the pixel values of a Black and white image in java

Tags: java, image-processing

I am new to image processing. I am trying to get the pixel values of an image in Black and white. I have searched on here but cannot find the right way to go about it. I saw a lot of post on RGB values but am looking for a sample with specifically black and white values which i believe would be an M x N x 1  array. I was wondering how this can be accomplished in java.

Comment: What's wrong with RGB values ? `rgb(0,0,0)`  for black and `rgb(255,255,255)` for white.

Comment: Please, read this section before asking questions on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Your question is too ambiguous to be answered without editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent black and white with RGB value. `rgb(0,0,0)` for black and `rgb(255,255,255)` and shades of grey: rgb(240,240,240) , rgb(128,128,128) [etc](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/gray-color.htm).

If you want to convert color to greyscale see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710560/how-to-convert-colors-to-grayscale-in-java-with-just-the-java-io-library).

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Java you use a BufferedImage to represent an image. The BufferedImage contains a 1D array of length Width x Height X Channels (image dimensions). To access the pixel values, a really simple solution is to use the Raster:

```
BufferedImage image = ... // A gray level or binary image
WritableRaster wr = image.getRaster() ;
for (int y=0 ; y < image.getHeight() ; y++)
    for (int x=0 ; x < image.getWidth() ; x++)
        int pixelvalue = wr.getSample(x, y, 0) ;
```

pixelvalue will be in a different ranges according to the image encoding (image.getType()):

- TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, range = [0,1], black = 0 and white = 1.
- TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, range = [0,255], black = 0 and white = 255.
- TYPE_USHORT_GRAY, range = [0,65535], black = 0 and white = 65535.

The fastest way to access the pixels is to use the DataBuffer, but it's a little bit more complex.